# Meteor - Get {{_id}} from tr data attribute to then make necessary mongo changes

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a basic data table that I am displaying mongo data.

For example: Mongo record has color key and value could be blue, red, green, etc...

Using Meteor I want to setup a click event where I can obtain the value of the  element but also know the Mongo Id of the record . I can then run the necessary Mongo queries to remove from the table.

When I use the code below the Mongo Id always displays with undefined value. I have stripped the code snippets to reduce the space of this post...

```
<div class = "tableview">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        {{#each values}}
            <tr data-mongoId="{{_id}}">
                <td>{{color}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</div>
```

----js below-----

```
Template.tableview.events = {

'click tr': function (event) {
        var theRowThatWasClicked = event.target;
        var mongoIdOfThatRow = $(theRowThatWasClicked).data("mongoId");
        console.log(mongoIdOfThatRow);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the data-context in `this._id` and get the mongoId of the item w/o storing the data in the DOM.